What foregroundServiceType to use for Android Auto Service ("extends CarAppService")
like the title says, I'm trying to figure out which foregroundServiceType to use for Android Auto, which requires a Service that extends CarAppService
As part of updating my app to support SDK 34, adding foregroundServiceType to every Service defined in AndroidManifest.xml is now required.
But, none of the possible values for foregroundServiceType seem to fit this case. I've looked for some examples in github.com but I only found 1 that even used it and it was set to 'location' which I don't think fits.
Even Android's documentation of this doesn't use foregroundServiceType.. but since every app needs to target SDK 34 by the end of Aug I have a feeling others are going to have the same question here shortly.

Quoting the docs that you linked to, "When the app is running in the car display, the system will not consider it as being in the foreground... To reliably get location for your car app, we recommended that you use a foreground service.". The implication to me is that they are not expecting it to be a foreground service just because you are extending CarAppService. So... are you sure that you need a foreground service and hence foregroundServiceType?

(sorry - i always forget how to enter a newline in S.O. comments and ended up adding this early)


are you sure that you need a foreground service and hence foregroundServiceType?


I'm not sure, no. I was under the impression every  in the manifest required a foregroundServiceType but I'm happy to be wrong if that's not the case


I was under the impression every  in the manifest required a foregroundServiceType

No, only those that are started via startForegroundService() and call startForeground() need to declare a foregroundServiceType.
CarAppService, like many cases where we have to extend magic Service subtypes, is a bound service, so its lifetime is determined by the service connection. The reason they call out location needing a foreground service is due to privacy concerns and the nature of permissions around locations, not service lifetime concerns.
So, unless you encounter some problems that can be solved by making your CarAppService be a foreground service, I would not worry about foregroundServiceType.
